# Do I need to update my Australian student visa to show my new passport details?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, australia, study, passport-renewals

I am in Australia on a student visa. Since my Indian passport was about to expire, I renewed it and have a new passport issued by India. Do I need to update the Australian visa with new passport details (since I will be travelling back home). If I do, how long will it take for it to be updated? What is the procedure?

Comment: While this question does contain the word "student", it's applicable to updating Australian visas of any kind.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, you need to update it**, or you may experience delays at the airport.  [You can update your details either immediately online via ImmiAccount, or by submitting an application](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/visa/visa#New%20passport).